# How to hang very heavy (marble, granite, quartz, etc.) shelves on drywall and studs?

Tags: shelving, granite, marble

I am planning a kitchen remodel and I have been looking into hanging some kind of stone-ish shelves on one wall. Surprisingly, I'm having a hard time finding much information on the feasibility of this idea. I know that these shelves will be very heavy, but I wonder if it is possible to anchor them to studs through the drywall, or if I will need to do something more difficult to ensure that the shelves are stable. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: We used these [floating countertop support brackets](http://www.countertopbracket.com/category-s/1823.htm), which worked great.

Comment: @user24147's link is what I'd suggest using as well--assuming you want 'hidden' brackets. You're going to have to open up the wall to attach them to the wide-side of the stud. And if you're opening up the wall, you might as well beef up the wall by adding sistered studs. How many shelves per wall are you wanting to add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anchoring them to studs is just fine, your main problem is going to be getting brackets that will support that amount of weight. The amount of weight each bracket will support will be printed on the package. I would consult your granite or stone supplier for weights of their products.

You MUST make sure that you're anchored into studs, though, and preferably with three inch wood screws that are NOT drywall screws.

Comment: If it's REALLY heavy you might even want to use lag bolts

Comment: If you need to use a lag bolt I'd be worried about structural deflection.

Comment: Any TV mounting kit I've ever seen comes with lags.  Obviously you need to account for what the structure can hold, but a lot of screws can't actually hold that much shear weight - screw heads are thin and can break off in the right situations. Lags are just a lot more heavy duty and having a hex head makes them easier to tighten without worrying about stripping.

Comment: Better to use threaded rod, drill through the stud and use a fender washer under the nut on the other side. Or use structural wood screws like TimberLOK. Lag bolts can suffer pullout, they don't bite deep enough into the wood.